# In Ruby, how does one add to an object a method with access to variables in outer scope?

Tags: ruby, methods, lambda, lexical-scope

I'm new to Ruby. I'm at the stage where I'm unsuccessfully attempting to write things in Ruby as I would in some other language.

I'm trying to add a method to an object – a humble array, let's say. Not to all arrays, just to one specific one. This method must have access to a variable in outer scope.

My understanding is that I can use `def` to add a method to an object, but that methods do not have access to variables in outer scope. For that I'd need to use `lambda` or `Proc.new`, but I can't see how I'd "attach" the lambda/proc to the array as a property.

In JavaScript this is straightforward, as this silly example demonstrates:

```
var x = 3
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4]

array.multiply_by_x = function() {
  var i = this.length
  while (i--) {
    this[i] *= x
  }
}
```

Is something similar to the above possible in Ruby?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use def keyword to define the method here because it will introduce another scope.
If you would like to define a method to only a specific object, then you have to define it in singleton class.

```
x = 3
array = [1, 2, 3, 4]

array.define_singleton_method(:multiply_by_x) do
  self.map!{|e| e * x }
end
```

But if you are are using Ruby 1.8.x, you have to do this:

```
(class << array; self; end).send(:define_method, :multiply_by_x) do
  self.map!{|e| e * x }
end
```

Note: It's not related to this question, but if you would like to see [different ways to define singleton methods.](http://web.archive.org/web/1/http://wowkhmer.com/2011/01/15/different-ways-to-define-singleton-methods-in-ruby)

Comment: `singleton_class` is defined in `ActiveSupport`, so in vanilla 1.8 you would have to do `(class << array; self; end).send...`

Comment: Excellent! This is exactly what I was after. Now to do some reading to try to understand what it's actually doing and why `x` is accessible in this case.

Comment: @davidchambers, blocks in Ruby are closures in other languages. Read more here http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_blocks.html

Answer (score 1):

Monkey-patching `Array` would do this, but it would do it for all instances of `Array`.

```
class Array
  def multiply_by(x)
     self.map! {|n|
        n * x
     }
  end
end
```

If you want to arbitrarily monkey-patch a method onto an existing object, I don't think this is really possible.

One thing that you could do is use a `Hash` with a `lambda`:

```
x = 3
hash = {:array => [1,2,3]}
hash[:multiply_by] = lambda {
   hash[:array].map! {|num|
      num * x
   }
}
```

You'd then call the `multiply_by` lambda like so:

```
hash[:multiply_by].call
```

Comment: You can monkey-patch existing objects very easily: `a = []; def a.add_one; self<<1; end; p a.add_one`

Comment: @steenslag Wow, that's really sweet!

Answer (score 0):

I would rather do like that:

```
ary = [1, 2, 3, 4]

def ary.multyply_by(x)
  self.map! {|e| e * x}
end

p ary.multyply_by 10
```

As a side note, it is much better to use function parameters than highly-scoped variables. Scopes are a way to avoid clashes, not obstacles.